# What is the definition of a reduced $k$-algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I am studying algebraic geometry from the class notes of a senior, and he hasn't defined a reduced $k$-algebra in his notes.

I googled the definition but could not find it. I know the definition of k-algebra and also the general definition when $A$ is called a $B$-algebra but I am not aware of definition of a reduced $k$-algebra.

Can you please help me with this definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just an algebra whose underlying ring is reduced, meaning there are no non-zero nilpotents.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_ring

This is, by the way, the first Google search result when looking for "reduced algebra" (maybe your mistake was to include the ring in the search term).